# Avoid Apache calling ap_hook_check_user_id hook twice

Tags: authentication, apache2, apache-modules

I ran into weird problem in Apache. I have a custon auth module where the `ap_hook_check_user_id` hook is called twice which I can see from the logs. I have found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237773/696632) but that does not resolve my problem. I have also checked the source code of `mod_auth_basic` but there is not such check for double execution.

I have applied that fix to be connection-scoped. No avail.

If `ap_is_initial_req` the solution to my answer? What are the consequences?