# Apache module - How to check existence of directive in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache-modules

I am trying to write a sample Apache module to read config file whose file path is specified in httpd.conf like that:

```
<Location ~ /(?!.*\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp|tif)$)>
        SetInputFilter SAMPLE_INPUT_FILTER
        SetOutputFilter SAMPLE_OUTPUT_FILTER
        ConfigFilePath "/etc/httpd/conf.d/sample/sample.config"
</Location>
```

At command record structure, I do:

```
static const command_rec config_check_cmds[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1( "ConfigFilePath", read_config_file, NULL, OR_ALL, "sample config"),
    { NULL }
};
```

I also set:

```
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA SAMPLE_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF, 
    create_dir_config,          /* create per-dir   config structures */
    NULL,                   /* merge per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                   /* create per-server config structures */
    NULL,                   /* merge per-server config structures */
    config_check_cmds,              /* table of config file commands */
    sample_register_hooks   /* register hooks */
};
```

I could read config file path successfully. And now I want to check that if "ConfigFilePath" is not specified in httpd.conf, It will show error at console when I use "service httpd restart"

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd register a `ap_hook_post_config` hook and do the verification of required settings there. Be aware that that hook is called twice as documented in the answer here: [Init modules in apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743122/init-modules-in-apache2)

See an example post config hook implementation here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.3.0/modules/examples/mod_example_hooks.c

Comment: thanks for your answer, **but I still do not know the way to check existence of "ConfigFilePath"**. If this key exist, read_config_file() will be called. If I define a global flag (default is true), in read_config_file() i set to false. I will check this flag at ap_hook_post_config. `Is it right way?`

Comment: I'm assuming you store the value of `ConfigFilePath` in a variable in the server/dir struct in the `read_config_file` function and initialize that variable to NULL. So what you'd do is check that variable in the post config hook and return/log an error if it is not set.

Comment: I know this is very old, I am still struggling right now. Verifying a parameter set in `srv_conf` within `ap_hook_post_config` is pretty straighforward, as the server conf is accessible via `ap_get_module_config(s->module_config, &module)`. But how about directory configs? I am trying to verify every directory configuration before accepting any requests.